# Running Jupyter Notebook on Binder with spacy dependencies

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I want to try out [spacy](https://spacy.io/) in a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) using [Binder](https://mybinder.org/). When trying to run `load` on a model like:

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8a5aa70d40b9> in <module>
----> 1 import en_core_web_sm
      2 nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'en_core_web_sm'
```

I tried downloading the model using the requirements.txt, but that didn't work or the model was download in an area I don't have access to. Not sure.

Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/sislandemarcos/NLP-lab). Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `environment.yml` and `requirements.txt`. When your needs necessitate moving beyond a `requirements.txt` configuration file for Binderhub-served sessions, you should move the contents of `requirements.txt` to `environment.yml` following [this example repo](https://github.com/binder-examples/python-conda_pip). In your case though one of your current requirements.txt lines is redundant (and conflicting) with the spacy line in environment.yml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `environment.yml` and `requirements.txt`. When your needs necessitate moving beyond a `requirements.txt` configuration file for Binderhub-served sessions, you should move the contents of `requirements.txt` to `environment.yml` following [this example repo](https://github.com/binder-examples/python-conda_pip). In your case though one of your current requirements.txt lines is redundant (and conflicting) with the spacy line in environment.yml.

Answer (score 0):

spaCy models are not installed using the `requirements.txt`. You have to install them in your environment by running

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

For more information, see https://spacy.io/usage/models.

Comment: My files are hosted in GitHub and I'm using binder to run them. I don't have access to the terminal to run python commands or I don't know how to access it.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I had a look into your repo and saw that you are installing spaCy >=2.2 and the model en_core_web_sm-2.0.0. I don't think those are compatible. Maybe the install fails without you seeing the logs? You can check the compatibilities here: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases, e.g. en_core_web_sm-2.2.5 with spaCy>=2.2.2

Comment: The terminal is available via Binderhub-hosted Jupyter by clicking on the Jupyter logo in the upper left to go to the dashboard. On the dashboard you can select `Terminal` under the `New` button Or you can always run any shell command in a notebook cell by placing an exclamation mark in front of it. For running python code, you'll get a richer notebook experience using ~%run` rather than `!python`, such as `%run -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`. (Or for easier terminal access along with a notebook, you can use the JupyterLab notebook interface available by changing URL in Binder sessions.)

Comment: @Wayne That's it. Works. Thanks. If you add your comment as an answer, I can mark it as a solution.